# Python refresh login system code

Tags: python

I am looking for a way to - after you have chosen what you want to look at (main_screen_choice) - be able to choose something else without having to restart the program. Here is my code

```
users = []
victims = ['John Smith', 'Karen Jones', 'Kevin Tomlinson']
print ('>>>>> RauCo. Protection Corp. <<<<<')
user = input('Username: ')
def storeUser():
  users.append(user)
def check():
  if user == 'Cabbage':
    storeUser()
    print ('Welcome back, Master...')
  else:
    print ('INTRUDER')
    exit()
check()
main_screen_choice = input('What do you want to do? \nVictims, To Do, 
Exit\n(Case Sensitive!): ')
def checkMainChoice():
 if main_screen_choice == 'Victims':
   print (victims)
 elif main_screen_choice == 'To Do':
   print ('Have a shower - you stink!')
 elif main_screen_choice == 'Exit':
   exit()
 else:
   print ('Error: Not a valid option, please run program again')
checkMainChoice()
```

Comment: Call `input` again?

Comment: Learn how loops work, e.g. https://www.learnpython.org/en/Loops and wrap your input into a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Just repeatedly go back to the point where you ask for input and run the corresponding behaviour.

This is commonly implemented with a `while` loop. As is, your code would look like this:

```
while True:
    main_screen_choice = input('What do you want to do? \nVictims, To Do,
        Exit\n(Case Sensitive!): ')
    checkMainChoice()
```

But I don't like global variables, and I would suggest you to give a parameter to your `checkMainChoice` function:

```
def checkMainChoice(choice):
    if choice == 'Victims':
        print (victims)
    elif choice == 'To Do':
        print ('Have a shower - you stink!')
    elif choice == 'Exit':
        exit()
    else:
        print ('Error: Not a valid option, please run program again')
```

Then, the `while` loop would become:

```
while True:
    main_screen_choice = input(...)
    checkMainChoice(main_screen_choice)
```

---

Several remarks as a side-note:

- Indentation in Python is usually four spaces. Besides, you really need to skip lines in order to make your code readable.
- The usage in Python is to name variables in `mixedCase` and methods/functions in `lower_case_with_underscores`.
- You notify that options are case-sensitive, which is not really comfortable for that kind of textual menus. You can easily solve this by setting the input in lowercase with the `lower` method: `choice = input(...).lower()`. Then, you will compare the input to lowercase strings: `'to do'`, `'exit'`...

Comment: After adding the while loop, when i answer what i want to do, it just asks me again what i want to do

Comment: @TylerRauer Well, if that's not what you asked for, then your question wasn't really clear